# Notations in Coq

Tags: coq

I want to use the notations to represent the predicate **test** as follows:

```
Variable A B : Type.

Inductive test : A -> B -> A -> B -> Prop :=
| test1 : forall a1 a2 b1 b2,
    a1 \ b1 || a2 \ b2
where "c1 '\' st '||' c2 '\' st'" := (test c1 st c2 st')
.
```

However, the Coq has an error:
   [image]

Why this notation cannot be accepted in Coq?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The notation is accepted, it's actually that Coq is incorrectly parsing your use of the notation within the definition of `test1`. To correctly parse this notation you need to adjust the parsing levels of its terms. You can do that with a reserved notation, since these `where` clauses for notation within an inductive don't support the syntax for configuring the notation:

```
Variable A B : Type.

Reserved Notation "c1 '\' st '||' c2 '\' st'" (at level 40, st at next level, c2 at next level, no associativity).

Inductive test : A -> B -> A -> B -> Prop :=
| test1 : forall a1 a2 b1 b2,
    a1 \ b1 || a2 \ b2
where "c1 '\' st '||' c2 '\' st'" := (test c1 st c2 st')
.
```

I don't have a good intuition for what parsing levels work well (40 is somewhat arbitrary above), so the best advice I can give is to experiment and if it's parsed incorrectly somewhere then try adjusting the level.

Comment: It must be at level `50` or below because the `||` for `orb` is at level 50.  I admit, though, that I'm not entirely sure what form the conflict takes.